# Output a find with xargs to a log file

Tags: bash, logging, find, xargs

I have some code that works. But I want to output it to a log file so that I know what is being copied from one location to another.

```
echo "find ${varSrcDirectory} -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%p\t%t\n" | sort -t $'\t' -k2 -nr | grep ${varFullYear} | grep ${month} | cut -f 1 | xargs -i cp '{}' -p -t ${varDstDirectory}/${varFullYear}/${monthNum} " >> $LOG

find ${varSrcDirectory} -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%p\t%t\n" | sort -t $'\t' -k2 -nr | grep ${varFullYear} | grep ${month} | cut -f 1 | xargs -i cp '{}' -p -t ${varDstDirectory}/${varFullYear}/${monthNum} >> $LOG
```

Here is the result in my log file

```
find /ftp/bondloans/transfers/out/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf %pt%tn | sort -t $'\t' -k2 -nr | grep 2008 | grep Jan | cut -f 1 | xargs -i cp '{}' -p -t /ftp/bondloans/transfers/out/testa/2008/01
```

But what I want to see is the actual file being copied from one location to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `-v` option to `cp`, so it will print what it's copying.

```
find ${varSrcDirectory} -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%p\t%t\n" | sort -t $'\t' -k2 -nr | grep ${varFullYear} | grep ${month} | cut -f 1 | xargs -i cp -v '{}' -p -t ${varDstDirectory}/${varFullYear}/${monthNum} >> $LOG
```

Comment: instead of a cp command and i wanted to use a move command i tried the following  cut -f 1 | xargs -i mv '{}'  but got this error mv: invalid option -- 'p'
Try 'mv --help' for more information.

Comment: The `mv` command doesn't have a `-p` option. It always copies the properties, since it's just renaming the file, so you don't need an option to tell it to do this.